# Is there a way to display a value of a variable in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

There's some model:

[image]

Is it possible to display a gain parameter on this model as a value, not a symbol?

Comment: If the size of the block is large enough then the value is displayed on the block, if it is not then `K` is displayed.  Basically you need to resize the block. Note that if the gain is defined using a MATLAB variable name then that name will appear, not its numeric value, and there is no way to change that behaviour.  You can however have a value displayed as part of the name.  (@Sardar_Usama, the default gain has always been one, and `1` appears instead of `K` if the size of the block is large enough.)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change the graphical appearance of the block (size in this case) you you can use the "block annotation" feature wich is in the right click menu "block properties". Then you will see the gain parameter below the block name as text... (You can display any of the properties that the block has)